# How to send variable to middleware using jquery ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, jquery-ajaxq

How do I access the variable `word` in my middleware sent from a JQuery AJAX call.

AJAX

```
 ....code 

 $.ajax({
          url: "/getWords",
          word: word,   //value wanting to send!!!
          success: function(result) {
            var myJSON = result;
            console.log(myJSON);

          }
        });
```

Middleware:

```
app.get("/getWords", function(req, res, done) {
         console.log("req.body = ", req.body);   //undefined ??? Looking for 'word' value

      });
```

req.body logs undefined req.params logs {}. body parser is installed.

Thanks

**UPDATE**:
This is my code now based on feedback:

```
//script.js

 $.ajax({
          url: "/getWords",
          data: {word: "value"},
          processData: false,
          dataType : "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          processData: false,
          success: function(result) {
                   var myJSON = result;
          }
        });

//server.js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get("/getWords", function(req, res) {
            console.log("value = ", req.query);  
    });
     });
```

Unfortunately in the console I get - value =  {} . What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You overdone it a bit :) Decide how you want to send the `word` data - either as a query string or request body. If first, remove `processData` and `contentType` (results in url form encoding), access `query` property. If second, switch to POST request and use `app.post()` method and access `body` property

Comment: Note for the first approach: keep the `contentType` option if you just want to get values without url encoding.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick (using the first approach).

Comment: No problem - glad to hear that the issue is resolved!

Answer (score 1):

`ajax()` method optional parameter "settings" does not have a valid "word" option. Please, use `{ data : { word : word} }` to pass the variable with the request (note that it will be interpreted as a query string, switch off `processData` flag).

**Sample request**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myurl',
  data: {
    myVar: myVal
  },
  success: (data,status,jqXHR) => {}
});
```

**Update**

In addition to Nelles answer, if you want to be able to access the request body, you should use `app.post()` middleware instead (assuming you want to send data via POST requests) + set `method` option on `ajax()` call correctly.

**Reference**

1. JQuery `ajax()` method [reference](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
2. Express `post()` method [reference](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method)
3. GET method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) on MDN

Comment: Thanks. How do I access this value in my middleware though?  req.body is still undefined :(

Comment: Hi @quietplace! You should be able to access the variable via `req.query` parameter (note that GET requests cannot have `body` - you should use POST instead then, see Nelles answer for an example)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest promisifying your ajax call **only if you are running the ajax** with nodeJS on the server side - the following works for me like a charm.

> If you do not want to promisify just try the code contained within the /////

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export const myFunc = word => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      ///// don't use 3 lines before this if running ajax on client side

        var args = {
            "word": word
        }
        $.ajax({

            url: "/getWords",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : args,
            error: function(err) {
                reject(err)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                resolve(data)
            }
        })

    ///// don't use after this if client side

    })
})
```

Comment: `$.ajax()` already returns a promise.  The OP just has to use that promise instead of the `error` and `success` properties.  So, there is no reason to manually promisify  something that already returns a promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are correct.  The exception can be if you are using jquery library on the server side instead of (for example) axios.  I was unsure of the usage so I provided the promisify option also.